# how to refresh the img src when src is change while using magnifier js?

Tags: javascript

I am using Image Magnifier http://asp-net-by-parijat.blogspot.in/2014/09/jquery-zoom-image-on-mouseover-in.html to magnify the image. It is working fine but i am using java script to change the src of image but the magnify don't refresh on hover it still show the old image but the image is changed.
My script to change image:

```
function SwitchPic(a) {
    $("#img").attr("src", a );
    $("#example4").attr("href", a );
}
```

My HTML code where i am using Magnifier js

```
<img data-toggle="magnify" id="img" style="width:288px;" alt="example4" src="~/Images/Product/abc.jpg" />
```

HTML where i call the java script to change the image src

```
<a onclick='SwitchPic("/Images/Products/xyz.jpg")'>
    <img class="thumbnail" style="width: 128px; display:inline-block;" src="~/Images/Products/xyz.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: can you provide https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the Magnify code, you see this initializer:

```
$('[data-toggle="magnify"]').each(function () {
    var $mag = $(this);
    $mag.magnify()
})
```

The reason your magnified image isn't getting updated is the Magnify initializer has already run and isn't watching for any `src` changes. You can fix it by adding a manual call in `SwitchPic`:

```
function SwitchPic(a) {
  img = $("#img")
  img.attr("src", a );
  img.magnify()
}
```

Here's a [proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/aqvmad9b/1/).

Comment: The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqvmad9b/) I linked to is working. Can you create one showing your problem?

Comment: the JSFiddle you have linked is also not working image is not zoomed upon hover